# Support for 4K @ 60Hz on Acer Aspire ES1-572 running Arch Linux

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, hdmi

I am trying to determine whether it is possible to get a 4K monitor running with a refresh rate of 60Hz on the above laptop. I understand that it is possible to get 4K resolution with a refresh rate of 30 Hz, using the HDMI 1.4 port (HDMI 1.4 only gives a max of 30Hz at 4K), but this isn't good enough for me due to the laggy mouse movement.

The graphics card of the laptop is an Intel HD 520. This graphics card does indeed support 4K @ 60Hz. The problem is that the laptop doesn't have a DisplayPort or a HDMI 2.0 port.

I have come up with the following solution which, in theory should give me 4K @ 60Hz. I just  want to know whether it would work in practice before going out and buying a nice 4K monitor.

The theoretical solution I came up with is to connect a USB-A - UDB-C cable into the laptop, then connect this to a USB-C - HDMI 2.0 adapter and then connect this to the HDMI 2.0 port on the 4K display.

Any thoughts on this (or other potential solutions, if any), would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!
￼

Comment: Do you get 4K@60Hz on the onboard screen?

Comment: No. It is 1366 x 768 resolution.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong in my reasoning here, but this page states that the graphics card can support 4K @ 60Hz: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-520.149940.0.html

Comment: Your reasoning has forgotten this point: The maximum theoretical capabilities of a given component are not the same thing as the actual capabilities in reality given that component's integration into a larger system. As you've noted the presence of the HDMI 1.4 several limits the effective capabilities of your system. A dongled series of adapters may meet your needs, or it may not. What type of USB connectors does your laptop have, and why are you planning to adapt USB-A to USB-C and then to HDMI, when you could go directly from USB-A to HDMI.

Comment: Yes good point. I was unable to find any USB type A to HDMI 2.0 adapters online (only type C to HDMI 2.0), hence I thought I needed a USB type A to USB type C adapter first. The laptop has a HDMI port (HDMI 1.4), two USB 2.0 ports and one USB 3.0 port.

Comment: In general, you want to search first using the version. So not USB-A, but USB3. These will likely default to the primary connector type, which is A. USB-C is a connector introduced with USB3: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-External-Monitor-Graphics-USB32HD4K/dp/B00OD37KHG

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for your help. I will try this solution, if it doesn't work I'll just have to make do with 30 Hz :)